# Sending an SMS in Skype using my mobile number

Tags: skype, sms

I want to use Skype to send SMSs overseas, and sent a test SMS or two to a friend. He got the SMSs alright, but couldn't directly reply since, by default, Skype was identifying me as my Skype Name. So, in 'Options -> SMS settings' I changed the identification mode to be my mobile number, which means that my friend can now directly reply to my SMSs via their phone.

The only trouble is - the reply doesn't go to Skype. It goes directly to my phone - fair enough. But the conversation in the Skype SMS window only shows my SMSs, not their replies. Is there any way to have Skype show their SMSs to my mobile number in the SMS messages pane so I can stick to Skype, and not have to break out my mobile just to see their response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No,** there's no way Skype will know that your friend replied to your mobile phone, because Skype can't look into your phone.

Also, Skype can't receive SMS (yet?), so even if you provided your SkypeIn number as SMS sender, it still wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but i just found it "binging" and though it might be handy to update. under your skype account settings on the skype site, under "call phones" there is an option to chance your Caller ID settings. enter your mobile number in here and when you send a SMS or make a call, your mobile number will show up. this way, your friend can reply, but it will arrive on your mobile, not skype...

Comment: What's "binging"?

Comment: like googling, but with Bing....